# How to tranpose pattern sequence in Scheme macro?

Tags: macros, scheme, define-syntax

I wrote the following Scheme macro.

```
(define-syntax join
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((join (var ...) (val ...) ...)
     '(((var val) ...)
       ...))))
```

When I try it

```
(join (a b c)
      (1 2 3)
      (2 4 6)
      (3 6 9))
```

it returns the following result.

```
(((a 1) (a 2) (a 3))
 ((b 2) (b 4) (b 6))
 ((c 3) (c 6) (c 9)))
```

But my intention was to write a macro, which returns the following result.

```
(((a 1) (b 2) (c 3))
 ((a 2) (b 4) (c 6))
 ((a 3) (b 6) (c 9)))
```

How the transpose the way the pattern matcher itemizes the `var` variable?

---

**Update:** I was told, that the `join` macro in this question is illegal according to R7RS 4.3.2:

> Pattern variables that occur in subpatterns followed by one or more
>    instances of the identifier ⟨ellipsis⟩ are allowed only in subtemplates
>    that are followed by as many instances of ⟨ellipsis⟩.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry but I got it myself. This seems to work.

```
(define-syntax join
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ var val ...)
     (let-syntax ((j (syntax-rules ::: ()
                       ((_ (k :::) (v :::))
                        '((k v) :::)))))
       `(,(j var val) ...)))))
```